# nokia device vibration in a game using j2me

Tags: java-me, nokia, vibration

I want to make my phone vibrate when my game ends. I tried using

```
Display display = Display.getDisplay(midlet);
display.vibrate(2000);
```

but display.vibrate(2000) returns false and the device does not vibrate. 
Can anyone help.
I am trying it on Nokia C7 device. (Symbian^3)

Comment: Did vibrate work at all on the phone ???

Comment: yes the device supports vibrations

Answer (score 3):

According to [Display](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html).vibrate documentation "The return value indicates if the vibrator can be controlled by the application." If you are calling vibrate during destroyApp the VM might be ignoring the vibrate request.

Try calling Display.vibrate before you call MIDlet.notifyDestroyed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it works.
It worked for me on nokia e63

```
package ravi.vibrationClass;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class Vibrate extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
Form form;
Display disp;
Command vib,exit;
public void startApp() {
    form = new Form("Vibration");
    disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
    exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
    vib = new Command("Vibrate", Command.OK, 1);
    form.append("Press \"vibrate\" to make the phone vibrate");
    form.addCommand(vib);
    form.addCommand(exit);
    form.setCommandListener(this);
    disp.setCurrent(form);

}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    notifyDestroyed();
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable arg1) {
    if(c == vib){
    disp.vibrate(125);
    }else if(c == exit){
    destroyApp(true);
    }

}
}
```